# str_getcsv is broken, clips diacritics?

Tags: php, csv, diacritics

I have a code like this in a file that is UTF-8 encoded:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'cs_CZ.utf8'); //Can be commented out without effect.

$input = "Štěpán,Šafránek";
$result = str_getcsv($input);

echo $result[0]; //output = "těpán";
echo $result[1]; //output = "afránek";
?>
```

Notice the clipped strings those echoes produce.

Also this works:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'cs_CZ.utf8'); //Can be commented out without effect.

$input = "aaaŠtěpán,aaaŠafránek";
$result = str_getcsv($input);

echo $result[0]; //output = "aaaŠtěpán";
echo $result[1]; //output = "aaaŠafránek";
?>
```

As the input string is part of script there should be no problem with encoding, right? Locale is set correctly, right?

So what is wrong? My resolution is that str_getcsv() is just plain broken. Any alternative way to parse CSV?

It is interesting that on Windows it works fine but on Linux I see this behavior.

Related question here, but resolutions mentioned there did not help:
[PHP str_getcsv removes umlauts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579144/php-str-getcsv-removes-umlauts)

Comment: What encoding is your PHP file in?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390851/fgetcsv-is-eating-the-first-letter-of-a-string-if-its-an-umlaut

Comment: Setting the correct locale setting like  `setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE.UTF-8')` fixed it for me (strangely enough it doesn't for you), it is a confirmed & unfixed bug though: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55507

Comment: Yeah, it is strange. That is why I reposted as the bug description doesn't seem to be accurate enough. Maybe setting locale is forbidden on server?

Comment: Confirmed : setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE.UTF-8') or whatever appropriate language, does fix the diacritics problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fgetcsv is eating the first letter of a String if it's an Umlaut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390851/fgetcsv-is-eating-the-first-letter-of-a-string-if-its-an-umlaut)